# How to retrieve cluster number for each customer belongs to alongside centroids in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

I have a dataset of over 20000 rows. where each row is a unique customer.
 I did k-mean clustering and output look like this.

```
str(km.out.best)

List of 9
 $ cluster     : Named int [1:24] 2 1 1 3 4 2 6 4 5 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:24] "nr_pxx_sxx" "sxxxxxxxx
 $ centers     : num [1:10, 1:20000] -0.1806 -0.3596 -0.7953 0.0781 -0.5887 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ totss       : num 618756
 $ withinss    : num [1:10] 1294 68340 0 4363 2530 ...
 $ tot.withinss: num 184130
 $ betweenss   : num 434625
 $ size        : int [1:10] 2 4 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 4
 $ iter        : int 3
 $ ifault      : int 0
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
```

- I am wondering how can I get a cluster number alongside the value of the centroid. 
  So something like

  #Example output

  ```
  cust_id    centers  cluster_number 
   1         -0.1806      1
   2         -0.3596      1
   3        -0.7953       2
   4         0.0781       ..
   5        -0.5887       3
  ```

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: what is the centroid column? also it seems like you clustered the transpose of your matrix. $ cluster should give you a vector that is 20000 long

Comment: @StupidWolf its # its just to get centroids for groups. `km.out.best$centers`. well, can I decide based on these centers can I choose I threshold which cluster a customer should belong to?

Comment: yes.. but a center would have as many columns as your data, so the structure of your expected data frame is weird. What exactly do you mean by centroid?

Comment: @StupidWolf well its `km.out.best$centers`. could you pls suggest something. maybe totally wrong in mt approach. thanks in advance

Comment: @StupidWolf btw I am following this blog ` I am following this bog `https://www.business-science.io/business/2016/08/07/CustomerSegmentationPt1.html`

Comment: i tried to answer your question. Not very clear what you want to do with the centers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216165/discussion-between-james-taylor-and-stupidwolf).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is like this:

```
dat = matrix(runif(20000*24),nrow=20000)
dim(dat)
dim(dat)
[1] 20000    24
```

You don't transpose. Then you run kmeans, most likely you need to change the algo to MacQueen or Lloyd, and boost the max iteration for your data:

```
km.out.best = kmeans(dat,10,algorithm="MacQueen",iter.max=200)
result = data.frame(id=1:nrow(dat),cluster=km.out.best$cluster)
head(result)

  id cluster
1  1       5
2  2      10
3  3       7
4  4       3
5  5       7
6  6       6
```

Your centers look like this:

```
head(km.out.best$centers)
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
1 0.3775496 0.2755110 0.5222402 0.5884940 0.4679775 0.6600569 0.4986263
2 0.7126183 0.2803162 0.3942072 0.6419705 0.5341550 0.5711218 0.5053729
3 0.6413244 0.6578503 0.5333248 0.4661831 0.5552559 0.5561365 0.4451808
4 0.3234074 0.6514881 0.4079006 0.6715400 0.4791075 0.4223853 0.6221334
5 0.6473756 0.6532055 0.6182789 0.5097219 0.5376246 0.5365016 0.4391964
6 0.6970183 0.4965848 0.5065735 0.3036086 0.4303340 0.3970691 0.5170568
       [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]
1 0.4594594 0.4345581 0.5701588 0.5906317 0.4385964 0.5218407 0.5516426
2 0.4628033 0.4235150 0.3608926 0.5285110 0.5168564 0.4346563 0.4062454
3 0.5265977 0.5334992 0.5376332 0.4512221 0.4647484 0.4902010 0.4676214
4 0.5939197 0.4694504 0.3937454 0.3384044 0.5686476 0.6172650 0.5186179
5 0.4654073 0.6234457 0.4909938 0.5596412 0.4936359 0.4770979 0.6025122
6 0.5156159 0.4322397 0.5056121 0.5290063 0.5568705 0.4741198 0.5276150
      [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]
1 0.5504851 0.2829263 0.5801165 0.4646302 0.6408827 0.4199201 0.5407101
2 0.5626282 0.6359599 0.5034993 0.4243469 0.3807163 0.5950345 0.4706131
3 0.3517145 0.2888798 0.6448517 0.3631902 0.5299283 0.4487787 0.4675805
4 0.4331985 0.4305047 0.4862307 0.4381856 0.3399696 0.4781299 0.5236181
5 0.6830292 0.6005151 0.5231041 0.5242238 0.4303912 0.3199860 0.3725459
6 0.2797726 0.4564681 0.5102230 0.6247973 0.4563937 0.6386731 0.5464769
      [,22]     [,23]     [,24]
1 0.5655326 0.5366878 0.6097194
2 0.4910263 0.3989447 0.4676507
3 0.4119647 0.3304486 0.3322215
4 0.5843183 0.4549804 0.6379758
5 0.6010346 0.6001782 0.6310740
6 0.5110444 0.6080165 0.6967485
```

It has as many columns as your data. If you want to append this and create a gigantic data.frame that has redundant information repeated, here goes:

```
head(cbind(result,km.out.best$centers[result$cluster,]))
     id cluster         1         2         3         4         5         6
X5    1       5 0.6473756 0.6532055 0.6182789 0.5097219 0.5376246 0.5365016
X10   2      10 0.4280159 0.5213989 0.6012614 0.6827887 0.4621622 0.4026403
X7    3       7 0.3671682 0.5811399 0.4086544 0.3584764 0.4406988 0.5859552
X3    4       3 0.6413244 0.6578503 0.5333248 0.4661831 0.5552559 0.5561365
X7.1  5       7 0.3671682 0.5811399 0.4086544 0.3584764 0.4406988 0.5859552
X6    6       6 0.6970183 0.4965848 0.5065735 0.3036086 0.4303340 0.3970691
             7         8         9        10        11        12        13
X5   0.4391964 0.4654073 0.6234457 0.4909938 0.5596412 0.4936359 0.4770979
X10  0.4308780 0.5798660 0.6022418 0.5895790 0.6293778 0.4796867 0.5552222
X7   0.3682988 0.6069791 0.3902141 0.6102076 0.3622590 0.5181898 0.5504739
X3   0.4451808 0.5265977 0.5334992 0.5376332 0.4512221 0.4647484 0.4902010
X7.1 0.3682988 0.6069791 0.3902141 0.6102076 0.3622590 0.5181898 0.5504739
X6   0.5170568 0.5156159 0.4322397 0.5056121 0.5290063 0.5568705 0.4741198
            14        15        16        17        18        19        20
X5   0.6025122 0.6830292 0.6005151 0.5231041 0.5242238 0.4303912 0.3199860
X10  0.5755699 0.3837531 0.6864855 0.3524426 0.5525500 0.6080231 0.6136993
X7   0.3925091 0.6750364 0.6796406 0.5637069 0.4988824 0.5664360 0.5727071
X3   0.4676214 0.3517145 0.2888798 0.6448517 0.3631902 0.5299283 0.4487787
X7.1 0.3925091 0.6750364 0.6796406 0.5637069 0.4988824 0.5664360 0.5727071
X6   0.5276150 0.2797726 0.4564681 0.5102230 0.6247973 0.4563937 0.6386731
            21        22        23        24
X5   0.3725459 0.6010346 0.6001782 0.6310740
X10  0.5897833 0.5092839 0.4041542 0.4247683
X7   0.4674218 0.5450985 0.5607961 0.4179112
X3   0.4675805 0.4119647 0.3304486 0.3322215
X7.1 0.4674218 0.5450985 0.5607961 0.4179112
X6   0.5464769 0.5110444 0.6080165 0.6967485
```